# android and flash: can android access the webcam inside an web page?

Tags: android, flash

I have a very stupid question: can android (I use samsung galaxy S2 mobile) can access teh webcam ?

In my flash application, I got a flash security alert that allows to autorize or deny the access to webcam.

When I run this flash, it never shows this security alert and then It does not access the webcam. 
I do tests for instance with the website http://www.dialogoo.com : works fine on my PC, works fine on my galaxy s2, but since it never shows me the autorization dialog, I cannot stream my webcam.

Any idea ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer :
no that won't work